# Setting a specific xlsx file to always open a unique EXCEL.EXE process

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, process, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel file that contains some visual basic forms used for data validation and entry. However, I'd like to be able to copy and paste from other open spreadsheets occasionally. The problem is that, when the form boxes are open, it blocks manipulation of other spreadsheets.

One way I discovered to get around this problem is opening a new instance of excel by typing excel.exe /x in the run box. However, I'd like to avoid making other users do this (because they're apt to forget or get confused).

Is there any way to make a specific xlsx file always occupy a unique instance of excel? It would be even better if I could accomplish this without having the other files already open, but it's not a deal breaker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've created a batch file with this in it as a semi-effective solution:

```
start excel.exe "C:/path here/file.xlsm" /x
```